# Jquery garlicjs + ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, local-storage

I want to use [garlicjs](http://garlicjs.org) in combination with a user submitted selection of a combobox where data is fetched via ajax in a jquery ui tab into partly filled in form.

So dependently of the user selection (combobox), this data needs to be saved accordingly.

But when making a different selection and the data is loaded into the tab, the form doesn't fetch the filled in data from localStorage.

Help would be very much appreciated!!

EDIT: I pasted a part of my code to provide a better picture of the problem: http://pastebin.com/rA2YaHZ0

Comment: Begin by providing your relevant code would be a good starter, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i need to re-initialize garlic on the forms when loading a tab:

```
    $("#menu-tabs").tabs({
    load: function (event, ui) {
        $('form').garlic();
    }
});
```